# Add values to elements in Google Sheets drop-down list

Tags: google-sheets

I think I might be over-thinking, but since I have no experience with any kind of spreadsheet, I just don't know where else to turn.

What I'm trying to do:

[image: screenshot]

I want a drop-down list and each object in it should have a value, but how do I assign values to them?  For example, "Wood" should have the value 4 so I can divide 200(B8) with 4(Wood) to get that sum in the righthand cell.

Comment: I think this what you are looking for [Answered in other webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916596/excel-dropdown-with-name-value-pairs).

Answer (score 3):

You want to look up the ore-per-fuel ratio for the chosen fuel type. This is usually done with [`vlookup`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en). Specifically, the formula

```
=vlookup(C8, A2:C5, 3, False)
```

looks up the content of C8 in the cells A2:A5 and returns the matching value from 3rd column of the indicated range (column C). Thus, your formula for Fuel Needed would be

```
=B8/vlookup(C8, A2:C5, 3, False)
```

More generally, whenever you want to have numeric information attached to some text strings, a lookup table can be created and used for this purpose.

Comment: =B8/vlookup(C8, A2:C5, 3, False) will this work by just copy-pasting it cuz its getting error :(

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use the `if` formula. For example,

`=if(C8="Wood",8,0)` means If the value of C8 (input) is "Wood" then output the number 8. Otherwise, output 0.

To do multiple items, you would use simply add a comma. For example: `=if(C8="Wood",8,0),if(c8="Some other Material",1,0),if(c8="Another thing",7,0)`

You can also of course combine this with math.
`=B8*(=if(C8="Wood",8),if(c8="Some other Material",1),if(c8="Another thing",7,0))`

*Just be careful with your parentheses!*

Comment: `=if(C8="Wood",8,0),if(c8="Some other Material",1,0),if(c8="Another thing",7,0)` throws Formula Parse Error. A correct way would be `=if(C8="Wood",8,if(c8="Some other Material",1,if(c8="Another thing",7,0)))`

Comment: I dont know if this is different for you and for me, but all the , i changed with ; and it worked :P =if(C8="Wood"; 4; 0) otherwise it helped me :) thanks